# How do I pass JSON back to my AJAX Request from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-plus

I've built a simple hangouts application that notifies me when someone launches a hangout from on my webpage - outside of Google plus.

I'm at the stage where I've called my server side script that notifies me that a new user has initiated a hangout and I need to pass a message back to the hangout to display an updated prompt to the users. Something along the lines of - A support engineer has been alerted to this hangout and will be with you shortly.

I've read in the hangout data, including who has joined from the hangouts api and passed this to my server side code no problems. But I'm not sure how I pass information back to my hangout app via its ajax request.

Here's my ajax request using jQuery.

```
var hangoutUrl = gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl();
var personsInHangout = gapi.hangout.getParticipants();

var callbackUrl = 'http://styxofdynamite.bitnamiapp.com/notify.php?';

$.ajax({
    url: callbackUrl,
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        "personsInHangout" : personsInHangout,
        "hangoutUrl" : hangoutUrl,
        "topic" : params['gd'],
    }
}).done( function(data, status, xhr){
    //call was made process result
    $('.msg').html(data.msg);
}).fail( function(xhr, status, error){
    $('.msg').html("There was a problem contacting the server. (" + status + ")");
});
```

At the moment I'm not returning anything so I'm happily hitting the `.fail()`ideally I need to return something from notify.php back to this hangout application.

Sever side snippet:

```
$personsInHangout = $_GET['personsInHangout'];
$hangoutUrl = $_GET['hangoutUrl'];
$topic = $_GET['topic'];

$emailMessage = 'Hey Support Team, ';

for($i = 0, $size = count($personsInHangout); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    $emailMessage .= $personsInHangout[$i]['person']['displayName'];
    $emailMessage .= ' is currently waiting in the support ';
    $emailMessage .= '<a href="'.$hangoutUrl.'">hangout</a>';
    $emailMessage .= ' to discuss ' . $topic;
}

print $emailMessage;

$to      = 'support@team.com';
$subject = 'New Hangout Request';
$headers = 'From: hangout.monitor@team.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: hangout.monitor@team.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $emailMessage, $headers);

//return something to say that a support engineer has been notified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php's built in `json_encode` [docs](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to send back a JSON formatted response.  You will also need to send some headers in addition to the data.

```
<?php
// This tells the browser the following data should be interpreted as JSON, as opposed to text or html
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// Take any $data and format it correctly as JSON.  Works with arrays, strings, numbers
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you I can see the JSON response being sent with the relevant headers but I'm still hitting the code that is for when the request fails.

Comment: try opening up the developer console and looking at what the issue is.  You can see the response body, where your data should be, the headers of the response, and any other issues.  Also try `console.log` your fail parameters to see what information they include.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use json with jQuery and PHP you need to do 1 things :

First you need to send a json response in PHP :

**notify.php**

```
<?php
// your code, send mail, etc.

header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode(array(
   'foo' => 'bar',
)));
```

Then you have a declare that you recieve json data in client, with *dataType* option.

**Your client side :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: callbackUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "personsInHangout" : personsInHangout,
        "hangoutUrl" : hangoutUrl,
        "topic" : params['gd'],
    },
    success: function(data){
       console.log(data.foo); // Will display "bar" in debug console
    }
})
```

Comment: the default `dataType` for jquery is auto, which will actually detect the json and decode it if the content type header is set

Comment: It feels like you're abusing php's `die`.  A simple echo works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had also the problem. 
Your 'call back' URL is 'http'.This is blocked by google's rules.
You have to use 'https'.

```
var callbackUrl = 'http://styxofdynamite.bitnamiapp.com/notify.php?';

var callbackUrl = 'https://styxofdynamite.bitnamiapp.com/notify.php?';
```

Comment: Though it's simpler in any case not to provide the schema `var callbackUrl = '//styxofdynamite.bitnamiapp.com/notify.php?';` however the server must support https